# MySQL Load Data error

Tags: mysql, .net, race-condition, filesystemwatcher

Part of a Car Park database system i am developing involves loading data from number plate reading cameras into the database tables. Using the Bulk Loader object in the .net connector (using to experiment with single and multi-line files), I have managed to do this, however there is a regular, but intermittent error that pops up, and I am hoping somebody here can help me work out what is wrong and provide a solution

I am using a pair of filesystemwatcher objects to monitor locations where the cameras (entrance and exit) output their CSV data. on the "file created" event, another subroutine is triggered that then loads the contents of the file into the database. Code for this subroutine listed below:

```vb
Public Sub sqlloaddata_in(ByVal sqlfilepath As String)

        loaddatainsqlconn = New MySqlConnection
        loaddatainsqlconn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;user id=root;password=W1nd0ws;database=hystest"

        Try
            'instanciate a mysqlbulkloader, feed in the parameters
            Dim sqlbulkin As New MySqlBulkLoader(loaddatainsqlconn)
            Dim insertedin As Long
            sqlbulkin.TableName = "hystest.tblin_dupebuffer"
            sqlbulkin.FieldTerminator = ","
            sqlbulkin.LineTerminator = "\n"
            sqlbulkin.FileName = sqlfilepath
            'sqlbulkin.ConflictOption = MySqlBulkLoaderConflictOption.Ignore
            sqlbulkin.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1
            'load the data into the database. return the number of rows inserted into the variable
            insertedin = sqlbulkin.Load
            Debug.Print(insertedin & " rows inserted.")

            ' refreshdatagrid_in()
            'close and get rid of the connection
            loaddatainsqlconn.Close()
            loaddatainsqlconn.Dispose()
            'transferdata_in()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            'if bad stuff happens, do this
            'MessageBox.Show("Database Error: " & ex.Message & vbCrLf & ex.InnerException.Message)
            'Debug.Print(ex.Message & ex.InnerException.Message & ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message)
            Debug.Print(ex.ToString)
            'Debug.Print("Retrying insert")
            'Try
            '    sqlloaddata_in(sqlfilepath)
            'Catch ex2 As Exception

            'End Try
        End Try
        'dedupe_in()
    End Sub
```

this subroutine will run every time a new file is created (camera outputs a file every 10 seconds) however when running, it produces the following error (taken from the debug window):

```
1 rows inserted.
A first chance exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Fatal error encountered during command execution. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Error during LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ---> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\HYS Database\Raw\IN\INLIST_HYS,HN03KTG,1970-01-01,03-36-01-582.CSV' because it is being used by another process.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.SendFileToServer(String filename)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.SendFileToServer(String filename)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlBulkLoader.Load()
   at SmartPark_Data_Loader.mysql.sqlloaddata_in(String sqlfilepath) in C:\Users\<name>\Dropbox\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SmartPark Data Loader\SmartPark Data Loader\mysql.vb:line 201
1 rows inserted.
1 rows inserted.
1 rows inserted.
1 rows inserted.
1 rows inserted.
1 rows inserted.
```

in the example above, one file was successfully inserted, then on the second, the error popped up. this takes about a minute to appear, and in that time, several other files have been created, creating a backlog of events to be handled, which then get inserted properly.

This happens constantly, and i'm not really sure why. The ultimate layout of the debug window alternates between an error and then the resulting backlog of file events.

what can i do about this?

Comment: The error message pretty clearly states what the problem is: *"The process cannot access the file 'C:\HYS Database\Raw\IN\INLIST_HYS,HN03KTG,1970-01-01,03-36-01-582.CSV' because it is being used by another process."*  What part of that message don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

I think Mr. Steven Doggart noticed the appropriate error message:

```
 C:\HYS Database\Raw\IN\INLIST_HYS,HN03KTG,1970-01-01,03-36-01-582.CSV
```

This file seems to be inaccessible when the MySQL client code goes to read it.

Assuming this is the correct file name, which only you know, then you're hitting a pretty common problem with file system watchers. They fire their events when the directory gets changed.

So, there's a window of time between the moment when the program writing the file

1. creates the file, and
2. finishes writing it and closes it.

If your program tries to open the file in that window of time, this error could result.

Here is a way to solve this problem. Have your program, in a loop, try to open the file for reading (and then close it immediately) before passing the file name to the bulk loader. If your open attempt fails (throws an exception), sleep a dozen milliseconds or so and try again. Don't make this loop infinite: give up after ten tries or so. You don't want your program to hang doing this.